# Stuck on a difference equation which requires an A-level method

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

In the non-zero sequence
$x[n-1]+x[n+1]=ax[n]$
and $x[n+4]=-x[n]$

i) Find possible values of $a$.

ii) For what values of $b$ is $b^n$ a solution ($x[n]=b^n$)?

I need to solve this using only A-level knowledge, but have just been unable to do so. Any help/guidance would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Start with

$x(n+1)
=ax(n)-x(n-1)
.$

Then

$\begin{array}\\
x(n+2)
&=ax(n+1)-x(n)\\
&=a(ax(n)-x(n-1))-x(n)\\
&=(a^2-1)x(n)-ax(n-1)\\
\end{array}
$

$\begin{array}\\
x(n+3)
&=ax(n+2)-x(n+1)\\
&=a((a^2-1)x(n)-ax(n-1))-(ax(n)-x(n-1))\\
&=(a^3-2a)x(n)-(a^2-1)x(n-1)\\
\end{array}
$

and,
finally,

$\begin{array}\\
x(n+4)
&=ax(n+3)-x(n+2)\\
&=a((a^3-2a)x(n)-(a^2-1)x(n-1))-((a^2-1)x(n)-ax(n-1))\\
&=(a^4-2a^2-(a^2-1))x(n)-(a^3-a-a)x(n-1)\\
&=(a^4-3a^2+1))x(n)-(a^3-2a)x(n-1)\\
\end{array}
$

If $x(n+4) = -x(n)$,
then
$a^4-3a^2+1
= -1
$
and
$a^3-2a
= 0
$.

From the second,
$0
=a(a^2-2)
$,
so
$a=0$
or
$a
=\pm \sqrt{2}
$.

$a=0$
does not satisfy
the first.
If $a=\pm \sqrt{2}$,
$a^4-3a^2+1
=4-3\cdot 2+1
=-1
$,
so both work.

For part (ii),
in
$x(n+1)
=ax(n)-x(n-1)
$,
substitute
$x(n) = b^n$.
This becomes
$b^{n+1}
=ab^n-b^{n-1}
$.

If $b \ne 0$,
we can divide by
$b^{n-1}$
to get
$b^2=ab-1$
or
$b^2-ab+1 = 0$.
This is a standard quadratic,
and you should be able
to solve for $b$
in terms of $a$.

I am not sure if
part (ii) also assumes that
$x(n+4)=-x(n)$.

Comment: Thanks a lot, once I saw your first line I was able to follow through and got the same answers as you :)